# Will Grub share the EFI System Partition with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, 17.10

I'm curious about whether or not grub will share the ESP with Windows 10 bootloader.

I am planning on installing **Ubuntu Budgie 17.10** on my Windows 10 Laptop (Lenovo 700-11isk) and I want to be able to dual boot. If for some reason Grub overwrites the Windows 10 bootloader in ESP, is there a way that I would be able to boot into Windows with Grub?

I have also found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49165/can-grub2-share-the-efi-system-partition-with-windows, but it seems to be related to distros that you have to manually install.

Comment: Maybe your Windows is installled in `Legacy` Mode. Check in your BIOS settings which mode your are using. In `UEFI` mode there won't be any problem and both the bootloaders share same `ESP`.

Comment: I have it installed in UEFI mode, I used 'bcedit' in Command Prompt on Windows and the Windows Boot Manager is in \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi. Also if they share the same ESP will it automatically create a grub entry of Windows when I install Ubuntu Budgie?

Comment: You are good to go, Install `ubuntu`. If any problem arises and `Windows Boot Manager` breaks than you can use `grub` to boot into windows

Comment: `os-prober` is the tool that creates entry for `Windows` in GRUB Menu

Comment: You have to make sure Windows fast start up is off, or the NTFS partition is not fully mounted and os-prober will not see it. And Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. Then grub will not boot it, but you can boot directly from UEFI to turn fast start off again. Grub only boots working Windows so best to also have a Windows repair/recovery flash drive.

Comment: My Windows 10 is installed in Legacy mode. What should I do to install Ubuntu on the same SSD? What if I get a second SSD for Linux would it make any difference to the installation process?